# Rasterio projection woes converting raster to vectorized GeoJSON polygons using GDAL and OGR

Tags: python, geojson, rasterio

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong here: why my latitude coordinates are erroneously offset by about 20 miles when I go through this procedure:

1. I create a raster called `map_dataset` using `rasterio` from a bitmask with
   `transform = from_origin(map_dataset.bounds.left, map_dataset.bounds.top, 0.1396038590137322899, 0.1396038590755779296)` and `proj4 = "+proj=merc  a=6378137 =b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs"`
2. I check this renders correctly in QGIS (I have to manually set the CRS to EPSG:3857 to display it correctly).

[image]

3. I polygonize the raster with `gdal_polygonize.py -b 1 -f 'ESRI Shapefile' {infile} {outfile}  ".format(infile=f,outfile='scene_data/sun/polygonize.shp'` This produces shapefiles that, again, render correctly in QGIS.

[image]

4. I need GeoJSON (latitude and longitude coords, not Mercator) so I convert the shapefiles to geojson using `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON  -t_srs 'EPSG:4326' {outfile} {infile}`

This produces a geoJSON file with `"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },` **BUT that latitudes are all displaced by about 20 miles north**.

NOTE: if I use QGIS to export the shapefie to GeoJSON, it renders correctly. There is a difference in the data: QGIS exports the GeoJSON as MultiPolygons, `ogr2ogr2` exports the features as Polygons. The CRS is the same `urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84`

UPDATE
Adding `-s_srs epsg:3857` works as suggested by @user30184. But something is wrong with the projection metadata produced by my rasterio file:

GDALINFO reports the following on the file created by rasterio:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: scene_data/sun/sunlight_wk_25_dt_2021-06-25_day_hrs_14.96.tif
Size is 512, 512
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["unnamed",
    BASEGEOGCRS["unnamed ellipse",
        DATUM["unknown",
            ELLIPSOID["unnamed",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                    ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]]],
    CONVERSION["unnamed",
        METHOD["Mercator (variant B)",
            ID["EPSG",9805]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8823]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["northing",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (-11682237.240229927003384,4808566.985907219350338)
Pixel Size = (0.139603859013732,-0.139603859075578)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-11682237.240, 4808566.986) (104d56'35.96"W, 39d47'35.10"N)
Lower Left  (-11682237.240, 4808495.509) (104d56'35.96"W, 39d47'33.32"N)
Upper Right (-11682165.763, 4808566.986) (104d56'33.65"W, 39d47'35.10"N)
Lower Right (-11682165.763, 4808495.509) (104d56'33.65"W, 39d47'33.32"N)
Center      (-11682201.502, 4808531.247) (104d56'34.81"W, 39d47'34.21"N)
Band 1 Block=512x2 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Here is the code that creates that tif:

```
proj4 = "+proj=merc  a=6378137 =b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs"
new_dataset = rasterio.open(
    f, 'w',
    driver='GTiff',
    height=day_shade.shape[0], width=day_shade.shape[1],
    count=1, dtype=str(day_shade.dtype),
    crs=proj4,
    transform=transform)
new_dataset.write(day_shade, 1)
```

Comment: Did you try to help ogr2ogr by giving the source crs with `-s_srs epsg:3857`?

Comment: Damn, I thought I tried that. That worked! Want to put that as the answer and I'll accept, or is this whole affair too embarrassing and I should delete my question?

Comment: Don't hurry. There is something odd going on. Normally GDAL, and thus QGIS, should find the source crs automatically. That you need to define it manually may mean that your rasterio code does not insert the crs correctly. Do you have `map_dataset` as a file at some moment? If you do, does gdalinfo report the crs as EPSG:3857?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Could you see my updated question? I don't know what I am doing wrong in creating the rasterio geotiff, but it is definitely missing its projection info.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about rasterio. Add tags `rasterio` and `python` into your question and perhaps you can catch some expert. And perhaps edit the title because the real question seems to be how to use rasterio right.

Comment: done. thank you for your insights.

Comment: @metalaureate if you want your raster written with `rasterio` to be encoded in EPSG 3857, you can simply change your `crs=proj4` argument to something like `crs=rasterio.crs.CRS.from_epsg(3857)`. See https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.crs.html for more information on the CRS class in `rasterio`.

Comment: I will try that! Thank you.